# jQuery dialog box not closing till a function is executed

Tags: jquery, dialog

I'm using a jquery dialog box to alert the user for deleting a record in a table. Following is my code:

```
$('#deletebutton').click(function () {
    if($(this).attr('disabled')=='disabled'){
        //do nothing
    }
    else{
        var isDeleteYes = false;
        $('#delete-confirm').dialog({
                    height : 150,
                    width : 400,
                    autoOpen : true,
                    close: function( event, ui ) {
                        //alert(closed)
                    },
                    buttons : {
                        "Yes" : function () {
                            isDeleteYes = true;
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                            deleteFunction();

                        },
                        "No" : function () {
                                    isDeleteYes=false;
                                    $(this).dialog("close");
                                }
                    },
                    title : "Confirm Delete",
                    resizable : false,
                    modal : true,
                    overlay : {
                        opacity : 0.5,
                        background : "black"
                    }
                });


    }
 });
 function deleteFunction(){
   /*
    *
    * Logic for delete
    *
    */

 }
```

The problem is that, in YES button i'm closing the the dialog before the function call **deleteFunction()**. But it is not closing until the function completed its execution. The alert in close function is appearing as soon as i click YES or NO. But the dialog is not getting closed in the UI.

Comment: Are you using ajax call inside deletefunction() ?\

Comment: No. I'm integrating it with C++ using Awesomium. So I will make a c++ function call inside that. @AntoKing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description, it is because you are running a synchronous operation in the `deleteFunction`, (which means one script will run after one, if asynchronous means will run parallel).

`$(this).dialog("close");` script  will only update the dom to hide the element, to hide the element from the view the browser repaint has to happen.

In browser both javascript and repaint/reflow functions runs in the same thread (But synchronous) that mean one will run after the previous script is completed action, so even though the dialog is marked to hide it will not get hidden from the view unless the current script execution is over, and browser gets a chance to execute the re-flow.

One solution to short cut the problem is the use a timeout, if you want to execute the delete function in an async mode like below

```
"Yes": function () {
    isDeleteYes = true;
    $(this).dialog("close");
    setTimeout(deleteFunction, 1);

},
```

Comment: Thank you sir. @Arun P Jhony. Your suggestion worked. But the explanation is you gave is little bit confusing. Can you please elaborate briefly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling ajax in called method(deleteFunction) then make it  "async: true". It's working fine for me. I hope it will be work.